# An adjective with "knowledge"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms

I was translating into English when the dictionary gave me a list of synonyms for the translation of one word, and I'm not sure which one to choose.

Which of the following synonyms would native speakers use in this sentence?

> Knowledges of primitive people were very (*confined/limited/scanty/bounded/ bordered/restricted* or *narrow*).

---

For those who doubted that the plural form of *knowledge* exists:

Google Books reveals 453,000 results for [**knowledges**](https://www.google.com.ua/?gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=knowledges)

Comment: As I've written in the comment below, there are some answers about the pluralisation of uncountable nouns: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94082/when-can-you-pluralize-uncountable-nouns?rq=1 http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174610/sufferings-is-plural-though-it-is-uncountable-but-how

Comment: @ Mari-Lou A In the most daring dreams I wouldn't consider my English as flawless.Thank you for your opinion though.

Comment: Katherina, I have deleted my previous comments. It's clear my help is unwanted. As the saying goes, there are none so deaf as those who will not hear.

Comment: @  Mari-Lou A Wow, I thought I was quite polite. Didn't mean to hurt your feelings. It's unfortunate you took my words this way.

Comment: No feelings hurt. But thanking someone for their opinion is fairly dismissive. It means you've made your mind up. To be precise: I was offering concrete advice, not an opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Limited" and "scanty" would be the most common.

Confined, bounded, bordered, restricted, narrow, all imply that there is something specific limiting the knowledge in question. Sometimes this is the case. For example, a region may be ruled by a dictatorship which prevents foreigners and scholars from meeting the people in question. In that case, the word which would be used would be "restricted". But, do not use "restricted" unless the cause of the restriction is named, or it will sound as if you have used a thesaurus clumsily to replace a more common word.

Answer (score 3):

Katherina:

It's:

**into E**nglish

sp**eak**ers

Your sentence should be something like:

*The knowle**dge** about primitive **people(s)** **was** very (limited, scarce, restricted).*

"Knowledge" is uncountable and you can use it only in the singular.

See at

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/knowledge

knowl‧edge **[uncountable]**

Also, at **Google books**:

["knowledge of many things"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22their%20knowledges%20of%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22knowledge%20of%20many%20things%22)
About 110,000 results

["knowledges of many things"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22their%20knowledges%20of%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22knowledges%20of%20many%20things%22)
1 result

Further:

at the 
[**The British National Corpus (BNC)**](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/)

try to look up for
[no quotes]

[**knowledge about**](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=knowledge%20about&mysubmit=Go)

381 found

[**knowledges about**](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=knowledges%20about&mysubmit=Go)

1 found

**which clearly shows that the plural should not be used, even when talking about multiple things.**

Comment: @ Marius Hancu Thank you for your correction. Next time I will check what I write more thoroughly. In my sentense I wanted to say not "knowlege about primitive people" but "their knowleges". And I'm aware that "knowledge" is uncountable. But some uncountable nouns have plural form. For example, "territorial waters", "Sahara sands", "The snows of Kilimanjaro". So I suppose when I mean "what they know in general" it's possible to use plural form "knowleges"

Comment: But some uncountable nouns really are uncountable, and don't have plural forms.  These are called _singularia tantum_  . See this small portion of a list of uncountable nouns at Wiktionary  http://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_uncountable_nouns&pagefrom=KLEPTOLAGNIA%0Akleptolagnia&subcatfrom=K&filefrom=K#mw-pages  There are also thousands of words in English that have ONLY plural forms; these are called _pluralia tantum_  http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_pluralia_tantum (a single one of such words is a _plurale tantum_).

Comment: @ Brian Hitchcock Thank you for precise terminology. I've never heard of this terms before. I've followed your link and an article in Wiktionary confirms that there is a plural form "knowleges".

Comment: @Katherina You're supposing wrong. You should only use "knowledge" in  the singular, irrespective of how many things you intend to say you know. __And always with "dg."__

Comment: @ Marius Hancu There are some answers about the pluralisation of uncountable nouns: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94082/when-can-you-pluralize-uncountable-nouns?rq=1 http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174610/sufferings-is-plural-though-it-is-uncountable-but-how

Comment: I don't care. We're talking about "knowledge" specifically, not in general. Look at the stats from Google Books in the update of my answer. That's damning enough. It's possible, but very rare and sounds like a __barbarism__.

Comment: The plural is out there in published books, yes, see https://www.google.com/search?q=%22knowledges%22+grammar&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22such+knowledges+are%22 , but I consider that such usage is off.

Comment: COCA http://corpus.byu.edu shows that "knowledges" is used exclusively in anthropology. If you work in that field, be my guest and use it. They may accept it.

Comment: @ Marius Hancu Yes, "I don't care" sounds like a solid argument. Probably, we misunderstood each other. It's good, you aknowledged an existence of plural form of given word. If something is rare it doesn't mean we can't use it in particular cases. Nevertheless, it's a pleasure to have a discussion with such an intelligent man like you.

Answer (score 1):

*unknowledgeable* - *Unaware because of a lack of relevant information or knowledge* [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=unknowledgeable).